# onLocationChanged returns a few wrong coordinates on start. GoogleMaps

Tags: android

I face a problem of receiving wrong coordinates when I starts my locationService. 
onLocationChanged returns a point that 100-2000 m far from actual position of the phone. This is unacceptable! Accuracy of such dots are between 20-90.
My settings are like this.

```
    googleApiClient.connect();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1f);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

I wrote a filter that cut of faulty dots but there are some possibilities that this filter will not work.

```
if (points.size() == 1 && prevLocation != null) {
        float maxDistance = 100f;
        if (location.distanceTo(prevLocation) > maxDistance || location.getAccuracy()>MAX_ACCURACY) { //second point too far from first one
            points.clear();
            dbHelper.removeFirstPoint(track.getGuid());
        }
    }
```

Are there any guys who faced the same problem or just know why that thing is happened.
I assume that this problem is caused by GSM or WIFI location based response

Comment: That's more a problem related to the sensors, I'd take this bad value and then wait that the phone refines it and then update my UI but there not that much you can do about that.

Comment: Use FusedLocationApiProvider